# VBA Insert Rows to bottom of specific table with formula

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a spreadsheet with multiple tabs and each tab has a table.  I want a button per tab to insert rows to the bottom of that table (by not having to select a cell) and copy the formulas from the row above it.
Here is what I have:

-ask how many rows to insert
-default insert is 1
-otherwise, use that variable to insert at bottom and copy formulas

```
Sub InsertRows()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim j As Variant
   j = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows")
   If j = "" Then
      j = 1
   End If
   For i = 1 to j
      Dim newrow As ListRow
      Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
      With newrow.Range
         .Offset(-1).Copy
         .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
      End With
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to implement the `i` and `j` from the input into the `For` loop.

Comment: I think tables automatically add formulas?

Comment: Is there only one table per sheet?

Comment: @urdearboy yes, only one table per sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach:

- Add a generic procedure to add rows to a table
- Rows are added by resizing the table range
- Add macros for each button specifying tables' names in each

**Macros:**
Replace `Table1` and `Table2` with table names of each sheet

```
' Macros to associate with buttons
Public Sub InsertRowsInTable1()
    InsertRowsInTable "Table1"
End Sub

Public Sub InsertRowsInTable2()
    InsertRowsInTable "Table2"
End Sub
```

**Generic code:**

```
' Generic procedure to add table rows
Private Sub InsertRowsInTable(ByVal targetTableName As String)
    
    ' Ask user how many rows to ask
    Dim rowsToAdd As Variant
    rowsToAdd = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows", 1)
    
    ' If user didn't input anything, default to 1
    If rowsToAdd = vbNullString Then rowsToAdd = 1
    
    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Set targetTable = Range(targetTableName).ListObject
    
    ' Resize the table to add rows
    targetTable.Resize targetTable.Range.Resize(targetTable.Range.Rows.Count + rowsToAdd)
        
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't agree with the approach by OP to always add 1. What if I accidentally select the button and just want to cancel? In that case I would want 0 rows added

Comment: as you said, some additional validation would be recommended

Comment: For sure but `vbNullString = 1` seems weird. OP did have that in his post so not an issue with your solution. I'm disagreeing with OPs approach, not yours. :) The larger the number of rows to be added, the larger the benefit of your solution over mine so +1 from me. Mine uses a loop which can be time consuming in large numbers

Comment: Only comment I would have is that op clarified 1 table per sheet so I think this is a reasonable time to rely on `ActiveSheet` and save the time of hardcoding many sheet names

Comment: @urdearboy I took it literal, (I've learned a lot from you btw). your comment was perfectly valid. I thought about using `Activesheet` but in this case I guess it's possible people adding more tables to the sheet and then causing unexpected behaviors.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz can I add the ```PasteSpecial``` somewhere to make sure it copies formatting also?

Comment: @DeAnnaMartinez AFAIK tables (listobjects) keep formating when they are expanded

Answer (score 2):

Link your buttons to this macro which should be pasted in `Module` or `ThisWorkbook` in VBA Editor

---

```
Sub InsertRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim i As Long, x As Long
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim NewRow As ListRow

i = Application.InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows", 1, Type:=1)
Set Tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)

For x = 1 To i
    Set NewRow = Tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
Next x

End Sub
```

---

Using `Application.InputBox` lets you set a default (`1`) and set a variable type *(`Type:= 1` = numeric)* which will help with data validation by not allowing non-numeric inputs.

*Note this does not cover all edge cases so you still may want to add some data validation: for instance, someone could provide a negative number. In that case, 0 rows would be created. User could also provide decimals in which case excel will round to nearest whole number to determine number of rows to add. You may want to limit the input to positive integers as a result*

Comment: Per discussion with @Ricardo Diaz below, it's worth noting this solution is dependent on the assumption you confirmed (`1 Table per Worksheet`). If this is ever **not** true, then you will need to do some updating to this macro.